# How does "\x"+* work?

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, byte

I'm trying to make a filesharing program, so I open the files in readbinary, and read it, establish a connection, and I try to send byte for byte.

How can I send `b"\x" + (encoded bytes of the int from dataread[i])`?

I always gives me an error, also, if it won't work, how can I read exactly a byte? So that I don't get an int? (like `dataread[0]`, if the value is `"\x01"`, I get 1).

My code:

```
for g in range(len(datar)):
    esc = str(datar[g])
    if len(esc) == 1:
        esc = "0"+esc
    esc = "\x"+bytes(esc,"utf8")
    c.send(esc)
    c.recv(500)
    print(g,"Bytes von",len(datar),"gesendet")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'\xhh'` notation only works in *string or byte literals*. If you have an integer, just pass this to a `bytes()` object in a list:

```
bytes(dataread)  # if dataread is a list of integers
```

or

```
bytes([dataread])  # if dataread is a single integer
```

`bytes` objects are sequences of integer values, each limited to the range 0-255.

To send individual bytes from `datar`, that translates to:

```
for byte in datar:
    c.send(bytes([esc]))
    c.recv(500)

print(g,"Bytes von",len(datar),"gesendet")
```